# Using Kafka and Kafka REST Proxy server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I have two ends of an application:

1. Python Flask backend, which communicates using Kafka in the normal way.
2. A machine agent written in Go,installed on a client environment and communicates with Kafka only via Kafka REST proxy.

Now the question is can these two ends communicate? For example can my machine agent consume messages from Kafka via the REST proxy,with messages produced from the other end in the normal way? Or do both ends need to use Kafka REST Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

As long as data arrives in Kafka, it doesn't matter what protocol-hops you're using to get it there. I'd recommend using `sarama` or `confluent-kafka-go` instead of HTTP, though